# Defining specific URL in Django

Tags: django

In a school application, I want to configure 2 URL patterns. The first one is generic while the second one is specific. I want to use the `name` variable of the second one for the `{% url }%` tag. This is my implementation:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^school/list-students/?page=1$', school.views.liststudents, name='list_students_one'),
    url(r'^school/list-students/(?P<page>[0-9]{1,3})', school.views.liststudents, name='list_students'),
]
```

so that, say in my student **base.html** I can use

```
<a href="{% url 'list_students_one' %}">List Students</a>
```

Is there a smarter implementation of this method?

Comment: Are you trying to do [pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/pagination/)? More specificially it looks like you're trying to recreate a [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.list.ListView)

Comment: Yes I am doing pagination. Cool! Let me look at this! But my more important question is to put paginations as links

Comment: If I understand you right then `"{% url 'list_students_one' %}?page=1"` should work... although I havent tested this which is why I haven't put it as an answer..

Comment: Hey @Sayse, in particular, I want to access the url with the page parameter for the first page. Cool! I will explore this and get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your urls might not be doing what you think they are doing, `?` is a regex character that matches 0 or 1 of the preceding group (its not the get parameter you think it is!)

Second, You seem to just be recreating a [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.list.ListView), so switching to using that would solve most of your syntax problems..

```
class StudentListView(ListView):
    model = Student
    template_name = 'list_students.html'
    paginate_by = 10

url(r"^school/list-students", StudentListView.as_view(), name='list_students_one'),
```

Third,

> in particular, I want to access the url with the page parameter for the first page.

If you don't provide a get parameter then by default, it will access the first page, so your existing url is fine